# Dynamic button not working when clicked on - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am able to create the delete button dynamically, but the action that I have set for it doesn't execute correctly. I am trying to delete one item at a time. I have to only use JavaScript and I can not edit the HTML, but I have provided the code for it, so it can be tested. Any tips would be helpful.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
form.onsubmit = validateForm;


var add = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
add[0].onclick = houseList;
var lastId = 0;


var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";

var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
dropDown.type = "option";
dropDown.required = true;

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

//var title = document.createElement("h2");
//title = "Member List";
//newDiv.appendChild(title);*

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);


function houseList() {

  var li = document.createElement("li"); 
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dropDown.value + ' ' + age.value + " ")); 
  li.setAttribute('id', 'item' + lastId);
  ul.appendChild(li);


  var remove = document.createElement('button'); 
  remove.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete")); 
  remove.onclick = removeItem;
  // remove.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeItem()');
  remove.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeItem("' + 'item' + lastId + '")');

  li.appendChild(remove);
  lastId += 1;
  ul.appendChild(li);

  return false;

}

function removeItem(itemid) { 
  var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
  ul.remove(item); 
}

function validateForm() {

  if (age == null || age.value === "") {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (dropDown.value == null) {
    alert("Please choose a relationship");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You entered: " + age.value + " and selected: " + dropDown.value);
    return addToList;
  }
}
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<title>Household builder</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Household builder</h1>
  <div class="builder">
    <o class="household"></o>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>Age
                        <input type="text" name="age">
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Relationship
                        <select name="rel">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                            <option value="child">Child</option>
                            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Smoker?
                        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="add">add</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <pre class="debug"></pre>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to reduce your question some what? It’s rather long and I’m wondering if all of it is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the remove function that will remove all the ul elements, should get the related parent of the current clicked element like :

```
function removeItem(itemid) { 
    var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}
```

Code:

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
form.onsubmit = validateForm;


var add = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
add[0].onclick = houseList;
var lastId = 0;


var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";

var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
dropDown.type = "option";
dropDown.required = true;

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

//var title = document.createElement("h2");
//title = "Member List";
//newDiv.appendChild(title);*

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);


function houseList() {

  var li = document.createElement("li"); 
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dropDown.value + ' ' + age.value + " ")); 
  li.setAttribute('id', 'item' + lastId);
  ul.appendChild(li);


  var remove = document.createElement('button'); 
  remove.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete")); 
  remove.onclick = removeItem;
  // remove.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeItem()');
  remove.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeItem("' + 'item' + lastId + '")');

  li.appendChild(remove);
  lastId += 1;
  ul.appendChild(li);

  return false;

}

function removeItem(itemid) { 
  var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
  item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}

function validateForm() {

  if (age == null || age.value === "") {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (dropDown.value == null) {
    alert("Please choose a relationship");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You entered: " + age.value + " and selected: " + dropDown.value);
    return addToList;
  }
}
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Household builder</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <o class="household"></o>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age<input type="text" name="age"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
          <select name="rel">
              <option value="">---</option>
              <option value="self">Self</option>
              <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
              <option value="child">Child</option>
              <option value="parent">Parent</option>
              <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?<input type="checkbox" name="smoker"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your tip helped! I was unaware that I could use parentNode...I thought it was referring to ul. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has mentioned the `element.remove()` function removes that element from the DOM not the child as a parameter. You can simply tell the `item` to remove itself from the DOM with `item.remove()` in your example or any of the other suggestions where you get the parent element and then do `parent.removeChild(item)`. The benefit of the first method in your case is that you already have item, so there is no need to get the parent where as remove is a shortcut that might not be available in older browsers though.

Second I would not recommend setting your onclick event with `setAttribute` as that isn't compatible with some older browsers and is kinda hacky.

A more proper way to to this is with the `onclick = function`if you only want to add one function the event or the `addEventListener("click", function)` (`attachEvent` in very old IE) used in more complicated cases where you need to add multiple events to fire.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
form.onsubmit = validateForm;


var add = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
add[0].onclick = houseList;
var lastId = 0;


var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";

var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
dropDown.type = "option";
dropDown.required = true;

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

//var title = document.createElement("h2");
//title = "Member List";
//newDiv.appendChild(title);*

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);

function deleteFunction(item) {
  return function(event) {removeItem(item)};
}

function houseList() {

  var li = document.createElement("li"); 
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dropDown.value + ' ' + age.value + " ")); 
  li.setAttribute('id', 'item' + lastId);
  ul.appendChild(li);


  var remove = document.createElement('button'); 
  remove.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete")); 
  remove.onclick = deleteFunction('item' + lastId);

  li.appendChild(remove);
  lastId += 1;
  ul.appendChild(li);

  return false;

}

function removeItem(itemid) { 
  var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
  item.remove(); 
}

function validateForm() {

  if (age == null || age.value === "") {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (dropDown.value == null) {
    alert("Please choose a relationship");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You entered: " + age.value + " and selected: " + dropDown.value);
    return addToList;
  }
}
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<title>Household builder</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Household builder</h1>
  <div class="builder">
    <o class="household"></o>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>Age
                        <input type="text" name="age">
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Relationship
                        <select name="rel">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                            <option value="child">Child</option>
                            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Smoker?
                        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="add">add</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <pre class="debug"></pre>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeItem(itemid) { 
  var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
  ul.remove(item); 
}
```

This requires an ID, but is called with only an event reference:

```
remove.onclick = removeItem;
```

I'd suggest keeping the calling part and editing the `removeItem` function:

```
function removeItem(event) { 
  var item = event.target;
  item.parentNode.remove(item); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the removeItem function

```
 function removeItem(itemid) { 
   var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
   ul.remove(item);  // HERE
 }
```

change the line to  **ul.removeChild(item);**

**BTW**

i suggest you to write any code that outside the functions you defined, in 
a function that caled after the window as been loaded ..
*(you trying access a dom elements that has not been created yet)*

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
```

// side note - remember to define any variables is a scope according to the range you want them to be known